# How to change the message on a given logic?

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

There are messages:

```
<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-1</SNILS>
        <Name>Den</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-2</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
    </Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-3</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
        <Sex/>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

output should be look like this:

```
<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-1</SNILS>
        <Name>Den</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-2</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
        <Sex>W</Sex>
    </Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-3</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
        <Sex>W</Sex>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

we must add a new element.

1. if it is not there
2. if it is not empty

added a block diagram:

[image]

put the value I got

```
<enrich>
   <source xpath="get-property('VALUE')"/>
   <target xmlns:t="https://services.rosminzdrav.ru/MedStaff" action="replace" type="custom" xpath="//t:Employee/t:Sex"/>
</enrich>
```

1. **how to check that the element is not empty?**
2. **how to add a new element?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. how to check that the element is not empty?

Use [filte](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Filter+Mediator)r mediator and check for condition

2.how to add a new element?

You can use, [payload/enrich/xslt](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Mediators) mediators based on your requirements